# Powering 5" display with LiPo batteries

Tags: batteries, lcd, discharge

I'm using a 4DSystem 5" display with Arduino MEGA 2560.
Normally Arduino is powered through a wall power supply but, in some conditions, I need to power the Arduino + LCD with batteries (for not more than 10/15 minutes).
I've tried with a series of two 320mAh LiPo cells (7.4V nominal voltage - max discharge current 640 mAh) but after only 2/3 minutes the display turns off.

From the data sheet, the display consumption should be 440 mAh so, theoretically, with a 320 mAh batteries the display should stay on for 40 mins.
I understand 40 mins is not realistic but 2/3 mins is very little time.

Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Comment: When you connect batteries in series, their mAh rating is not multiplied.

Comment: I didn't sum mAh: each cell is 3.7V - 320 mAh so the serie of the 2 cells is 7.4V - 320 mAh.

Comment: What is this *max discharge current 640 mAh* ? (BTW, current is not measured in mAh..). Anyway, what are the display specs? And how do you connect it?

Comment: Max discharge current come from the data sheet of the batteries (http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/628008.pdf): it's 2C where C is 320 mAh => 640 mA (I erroneously wrote mAh). Display specs is 440mAh typical consumption. I connected the batteries to Arduino jack and the display to 5V pin on Arduino. I also tried to power the display through a switching regulator (L5970D) but the problem is the same.

Comment: Have you measured the voltage of the batteries after the display turns off?

Comment: The battery voltage is 6V when it turns off. 
I did a test by powering only the display (no Arduino) ... here is the scheme: https://1drv.ms/i/s!ArwOTDsw1pUeh9tnvW9CsenHbKyhnQ
Here is a link to a video of the test with measurement of voltage and current (350mA): https://1drv.ms/v/s!ArwOTDsw1pUeh9toqRIRFs1kCgiRXg  After 2:30 the display turns off.